Next.js parallel routes showing 404 page not found upon hard navigation
I am facing a problem where hard navigation to parallel routes show 404 page not found but navigating via link component is working as expected. Current directory structure:
app
└── patients
    ├── @modal
    │   ├── [patientId]
    │   │   ├── @prescription
    │   │   │   ├── prescription
    │   │   │   │   └── page.js
    │   │   │   ├── layout.js
    │   │   │   └── default.js
    │   │   ├── layout.js
    │   │   └── page.js
    │   ├── new
    │   │   └── page.js
    │   └── default.js
    ├── layout.js
    └── page.js

The parallel routes are displayed on a full screen dialog which overlays over the main patients page. When navigating to /patients/new, /patients/123, /patients/123/prescription via link component, it is working as expected but when hard navigating to any of the links, I am getting 404 page not found, however, I want the parallel route to be displayed upon hard navigation just as it does on soft navigation.
Can this be done using parallel routes? I am not being able to get a grasp of how this is working. I searched over the web and I think it has something to do with the default.js page? Really need help on this one.
